# Which natural numbers can be represented as a sum of natural numbers raised to different powers?

Tags: number-theory, summation, diophantine-equations, natural-numbers

[Waring's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring's_problem) asks about natural numbers that can be represented as a sum of natural numbers all raised to the same power $k$. I'm wondering **which natural numbers can be represented as a sum of natural numbers *all raised to *different* powers*?**

To make this question interesting, one has to impose a few additional restrictions:

- If first powers were allowed, every natural number $n$ could be trivially represented as $n=n^1$, so **all exponents must be greater than $1$**
- If $1$ were allowed as a base, every natural number $n$ could be trivially represented as $n=1^{a_1}+...+1^{a_n}$, so **the natural numbers summed over must all be greater than $1$**

**Example:** $12=2^2+2^3$ (smallest number representable under the above rules that is not a perfect power)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to caracterize the way to represent $n$ as sum of natural numbers raised to different powers. I'll be using the residue $\text{mod} 32$ so I won't be using exponents larger than $4$. We can represent $n - (n \mod 32)$ using different powers of $2$ (raising to powers larger than $4$).

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
n \mod 32 & \text{Use:}\\ \hline
0 &  0^2+0^3+0^4 \\ \hline
1 &  3^2 + 2^3 + 2^4\\ \hline
3 &  2^2 + 15^3 + 2^4\\ \hline
4 &  2^2 + 0^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
5 &  5^2 + 0^3 + 2^4 \\ \hline
6 &  3^2 + 5^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
7 &  0^2 + 7^3 + 2^4\\ \hline
8 &  0^2 + 2^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
9 &  3^2 + 0^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
10&  3^2 + 0^3 + 15^4\\ \hline
11&  0^2 + 3^3 + 2^4\\ \hline 
12&  2^2 + 2^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
13&  2^2 + 2^3 + 15^4\\ \hline
14&  3^2 + 13^3 + 2^4\\ \hline
15&  2^2 + 3^3 + 2^4\\ \hline
16&  0^2 + 0^3 + 2^4\\ \hline
17&  3^2 + 2^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
18&  3^2 + 2^3 + 15^4\\ \hline
19&  2^2 + 15^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
20&  2^2 + 0^3 + 2^4\\ \hline
21&  0^2 + 13^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
22&  3^2 + 5^3 + 2^4\\ \hline
23&  0^2 + 7^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
24&  0^2 + 2^3 + 2^4\\ \hline
25&  5^2 + 0^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
26&  5^2 + 15^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
27&  0^2 + 3^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
28&  2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4\\ \hline
29&  0^2 + 5^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
30&  3^2 + 13^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
31&  2^2 + 3^3 + 0^4\\ \hline
 \end{array}$$

This means that the amount of numbers that cannot be expressed as sum of powers is finite (and bounded by 50000 aprox)

Comment: This may well be a stupid question, but how did you get the $50000$ approximation? Is it because of the choice of residue?

Comment: @recursiverecursion: note the value for $18$, (which is $50642$ and I think is the largest in the table) so you wouldn't have to check higher than that.  As only three of the entries use $15^4$, you could argue the number to check is about $10$ times lower.  Just add up the values in the table and divide by $32$

Comment: No, it's because for some of those numbers I'm using $3^2+2^3+15^4$ wich is a bit over $50000$ (50642 to be precise), so you'd need $n$ to be over that number to use that representation. I don't know if there's a better way to express it, but if there is such a way, it would involve using exponents higher than $4$.

Comment: That's it. Amazing derivation, thank you!

Comment: @pew Thanks! It took me quite a while... =P

Comment: You seem to have forgotten $n\bmod 32=2$. For these, you may use $3^2+2^3+3^4$.

Answer (score 0):

Every number divisible by $4$ can be written this way, by computing the binary expansion of $n$ and then adding $2^k$ if the $(k+1)$th digit is 1 in the expansion. Similarly you can express any odd number of the form $n+9$ where $n \geq 0$ is divisible by $8$. Not sure how to get the complete characterization of all numbers that can be written this way.